# Initializing JPA subentities when submitting JSF datatable

Tags: jpa, jsf, datatable, initialization, selectonelistbox

I've recently received a business requirement for my JSF app to edit rows of a datatable, in the table itself.

*The problem*:

the table is backed by a list of JPA entities, but the editable fields belong to their -**optional**- associations. So, as an example of such an editable `selectOneListbox` field, if I do:

```html
<h:selectOneListbox id="rca" value="#{mainEntity.associatedEntity.rca}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{rcaOptions}" var="rca" itemLabel="#{rca}" itemValue="#{rca}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

I eventually receive `Target Unreachable, 'associatedEntity' returned null` when submitting the table, for those rows where there is no associated entity yet, even if I left the `selectOneListbox` unchanged for those (null option selected).

*The questions*:

1. how/where/when can I elegantly instantiate new subentities when submitting the form, only for those rows the user acted on (ajax-less preferably), preventing the error shown above? Forcibly creating subentities in the model for all rows when first rendering the table is IMHO a flaw in design.
2. How can I programmatically ignore this `selectOneListbox` -or any other input field- from the entire JSF lifecycle, conditionally, just like if the field never existed in the request? I tried implementing several converters and validators but the validation phase is still trying to get the value reference, no matter what I try, throwing the error shown above

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you actually want to instantiate and persist new subEntities if the user has input something (transparently, without user knowledge? Else `<h:selectOneListbox ... rendered="#{not empty mainEntity.associatedEntity}" ...>` would prevent the exception and show the user there's nothing eligable to input. Otherwise, instead of feeding entities directly to the dataTable value, feed it a List of DTOs each decorating/wrapping an entity. The `selectOneListbox` value expression could then look like `#{mainEntityDTO.associatedEntityRca}`. On user input, create + persist a new subEntity.

Comment: Thanks Selaron! User has to be able to input an rca option, no matter if a subentity already existed or not for that row. If it didn't exist, then one must be created and persisted as part of the submission. I was hoping there was some JSF capability that I was not fully exploiting, before going for the decorators